# Subgroups of Prime Power Index

Tags: group-theory

If a prime power divides order of a group, then the group contains a subgroup of that order. We can consider the following natural question: *if a prime power divides order of a group, does there exists a subgroup of that index in the group?* The answer is NO, as $|A_5|=2^2.3.5$ and $A_5$ has no subgroup of index $3$.

Further, $A_6$ is also an interesting example in the sense that for *any prime divisor* of its order, $A_6$ has no subgroup of that index.

My question is: *is there a finite group $G$ such that for any prime power divisor of $|G|$, $G$ has no subgroup of that index?*

Comment: Most simple groups work. See the paper of Guralnick in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420530/if-g-is-non-nilpotent-and-m-is-non-normal-subgroup-of-g-then-g-m-p/420680#420680

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already gave such an example. $A_6$ has no subgroups of prime power index - see [this page](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_alternating_group%3aA6) for a list of all subgroups of $A_6$.

Comment: @Thanks for noticing it.